# Group timestamps by day in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-analysis

I want to combine multiple datestamps (datetime64) to a single row representing one day. Then I want to sum up the amount in the last column getting the total sales per day.

[image: Sample of the dataframe]

In this case I want to have two lines, with the two days and the total sales.
I have tried to solve my problem with the groupby operation, but it won't work.

Comment: Please either accept an answer, or tell us why none of the answers is acceptable. Thanks!

Comment: Pinging: Please either accept an answer, or tell us why none of the answers is acceptable. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The one-liner `df.resample('1d', on='timestamp').sum()`
[from Aeroxer Support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73921658/341970) is perfect, but it does not explain why your attempts with `groupby` failed.

In order to `groupby` to work, you would need a column with just the day in it. Then you could `groupby` by that day column.

Below is the example code. I add the extra column with just the day in it at `In [4]` and then `df.groupby('day').sum()` is what you are looking for.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:     'timestamp': map(pd.Timestamp, ['2022-09-30 11:21', '2022-09-30 20:55', '2022-10-01 10:35', '2022-10-01 22:42']),
   ...:     'sales': [99.90, 10.20, 5.99, 21.00]
   ...: })

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
            timestamp  sales
0 2022-09-30 11:21:00  99.90
1 2022-09-30 20:55:00  10.20
2 2022-10-01 10:35:00   5.99
3 2022-10-01 22:42:00  21.00

In [4]: df['day'] = df.timestamp.dt.floor('1D')

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
            timestamp  sales         day
0 2022-09-30 11:21:00  99.90  2022-09-30
1 2022-09-30 20:55:00  10.20  2022-09-30
2 2022-10-01 10:35:00   5.99  2022-10-01
3 2022-10-01 22:42:00  21.00  2022-10-01

In [6]: df.groupby('day').sum()
Out[6]: 
             sales
day               
2022-09-30  110.10
2022-10-01   26.99
```

You don't have to explicitly save the day in a new column, this works just as well:

```
df.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.floor('1D')).sum()
```

although I find it hard to read. See the docs on [`Series.dt.floor()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use resample

`df_1d=df.resample('1d', on='timestamp').sum()`

It will sum all data for all day or from another time